# Limit amount of text of a string

Tags: php, string, wordpress, limit

I'm using WordPress and I have a post which I want to grab and have the information post on the front page of my site.

I've managed to get it to work but it posts the entire article and I would like to just post a maybe 30 characters with a "read more" button at the end.

Below is the code I am using. Since I'm relatively new to Php so I'm a bit stuck.

```
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php if ( siteorigin_setting( 'blog_archive_content' ) == 'excerpt' ) the_excerpt(); else the_content(); ?>

        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'ultra' ) . '</span>',
                'after'  => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Here is the full content of the php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package ultra
 * @since ultra 0.9
 * @license GPL 2.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php if ( ! is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() && siteorigin_setting( 'blog_archive_featured_image' ) ) : ?>

        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php elseif ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() && siteorigin_setting( 'blog_archive_featured_image' ) ) : ?>

        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>


        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php if ( siteorigin_setting( 'blog_archive_content' ) == 'excerpt' ) the_excerpt(); else the_content(); ?>

        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'ultra' ) . '</span>',
                'after'  => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->



</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) which will give you a defined amount of words (not characters).

```
<?php  echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 5, '...<a href="'. get_permalink().'">Read More</a>' );?>
```

or use [mb_strimwidth](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) which will give you a character limit.

```
<?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_content(), 0, 30, '...');?>
```